# How to send an int from Python to an Arduino in order to use it as an argument for the neopixel function setPixelcolor()?

Tags: python, arduino

I am trying to send an int number from Python to an Arduino using PySerial, using `.write([data])` to send with Python and `Serial.read()` or `Serial.readString()` to recieve on the Arduino, then `.setPixelColor()` and `.show()` to light a LED on a matrix which position corresponds to the `int` sent by the arduino (I am using the Duinofun Neopixel Shield).

But It does not seem to work properly, and I can't use the Serial Monitor as I am sending my data as the port would be busy.

I have tried to input a number myself using `Serial.readString()` then converting the string to an int and finally putting in into my function that displays the LED.

It does work properly when I do this, but when I send some data over, all the previously lit LEDs suddenly switch off which can only be caused by a reset of the Arduino board as far as I know.

This is the python code, it simply sends an int chosen by the user

```py
import serial

a = int(input('Enter pixel position : '))
ser = serial.Serial("COM16", 9600)

ser.write([a])
```

And this is the part of the Arduino program that reads the incoming data.

```c
Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels = Adafruit_NeoPixel(40, 6, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pixels.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  String a = Serial.readString();
  int b = a.toInt();
  pixels.setPixelColor(b, 30,30,30);
  pixels.show();
  Serial.println(a);

  delay(1000);

}
```

All the LED switch off when I send some data, except the first LED which position corresponds to a 0 used in the `.setPixelColor()` function.

Problem is, the LED should light to the corresponding int sent by Python (e.g light the fifth LED for an int of 4).

Comment: The code you are currently showing sends an int from python and receives a string in the arduino.  So, if you try to turn on pixel 3, `a.toInt()` tries to convert ascii character 3 (which is an unprintable character, let alone not a digit) to an int and fails

Comment: To clarify, you need to send and receive the same type of data.  Either change to send as a string, or change to receive as an int.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, yes I should have been more conscious on that thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to send an `int` from your Python script. Just send a string and then convert it back to `int` on your Arduino. Also, you can verify the number simply on your Arduino code if the received value is valid.
Another problem with your Arduino code is you are not checking the Serial port availability which would return an empty string by `Serial.readString()`.

A simple approach is shown below but you can extend it for other pixels.

Python script:

```
import serial


ser = serial.Serial("COM16", 9600)
while True:
    input_value = input('Enter pixel position: ')
    ser.write(input_value.encode())
```

Arduino code:

```
#define MIN_PIXEL_RANGE 0
#define MAX_PIXEL_RANGE 100

Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels = Adafruit_NeoPixel(40, 6, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup()
{
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    pixels.begin();
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    if (Serial.available())
    {
        String a = Serial.readString();
        Serial.print("Received Value: ");
        Serial.println(a);
        int b = a.toInt();
        if ((b >= MIN_PIXEL_RANGE) && (b <= MAX_PIXEL_RANGE))
        {
            pixels.setPixelColor(b, 30, 30, 30);
            pixels.show();
            delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked perfectly (there is just a little error in the Python script, the definition of the port is in the loop, so we are basically trying to reopen at each loop).

Comment: While this solution works, you should really be sending the integer data as a stand alone packet to increase the transfer speed. An integer on most arduinos are 16 bits and a character takes 8 bits. As long as your integer is more than two long, the packet size will be increased. This may not matter in this solution but will matter if sending a lot of data or sending it quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You can communicate between Ardinos and Python really easily and reliably if you use the pip-installable package [pySerialTransfer](https://github.com/PowerBroker2/pySerialTransfer). The package is non-blocking, easy to use, supports variable length packets, automatically parses packets, and uses CRC-8 for packet corruption detection.

Here's an example Python script:
from pySerialTransfer import pySerialTransfer as txfer

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        link = txfer.SerialTransfer('COM13')

        link.txBuff[0] = 'h'
        link.txBuff[1] = 'i'
        link.txBuff[2] = '\n'

        link.send(3)

        while not link.available():
            if link.status < 0:
                print('ERROR: {}'.format(link.status))

        print('Response received:')

        response = ''
        for index in range(link.bytesRead):
            response += chr(link.rxBuff[index])

        print(response)
        link.close()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        link.close()
```

Note that the Arduino will need to use the library [SerialTransfer.h](https://github.com/PowerBroker2/SerialTransfer). You can install SerialTransfer.h using the Arduino IDE's Libraries Manager.

Here's an example Arduino sketch:

```
#include "SerialTransfer.h"

SerialTransfer myTransfer;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(115200);
  myTransfer.begin(Serial1);
}

void loop()
{
  myTransfer.txBuff[0] = 'h';
  myTransfer.txBuff[1] = 'i';
  myTransfer.txBuff[2] = '\n';

  myTransfer.sendData(3);
  delay(100);

  if(myTransfer.available())
  {
    Serial.println("New Data");
    for(byte i = 0; i < myTransfer.bytesRead; i++)
      Serial.write(myTransfer.rxBuff[i]);
    Serial.println();
  }
  else if(myTransfer.status < 0)
  {
    Serial.print("ERROR: ");
    Serial.println(myTransfer.status);
  }
}
```

Lastly, note that you can transmit ints, floats, chars, etc. using the combination of these libraries!